# How do I configure the Amazon DynamoDB region in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following code for adding an item to Amazon DynamoDB . I have set  the region to ap-south-1, but the item is getting added to us-east-1 region.

```
AWS.config.update({
    region: "ap-south-1",
    endpoint: "dynamodb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com"
});

var addDocumentToTable = function (tablename, item, callback) {
    
    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    var params = {
        TableName: tablename,
        Item: item
    }
    docClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
        retData = { status: true, message: "Successfully inserted", error: null };
        if (err) {
            retData.status = false;
            retData.message = "Failed to insert into DynamoDB";
            retData.error = err;
        }
        callback(err, retData);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the details to the DocumentClient has solved it.

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: Config.AWS.AWS_REGION, endpoint: Config.AWS.ENDPOINT });
```

Comment: Note that you might want to create the document client  in a global variable, at the top of the file, so that subsequent invocations that reuse a container can avoid spending time and resources having to set it up again.  If you need more than one region, create a global object and use the key as the region name, sort of like a mini cache of clients.